# Save Video from Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I create space detection code by using gray, gausian blur but now I dont know where to put these code to save my opencv video.
I already tried to put the code in random line but it only comes out of the file at the output, I cant play it and the video also just 5.6KB. I even tried to record a video for a very long time.
My code runs fine without save feature but I want to add save video feature:

```html
fourcc = open_cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = open_cv.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

these is my code that i want to be add save video coding from above :

```html
import cv2 as open_cv
import numpy as np
import logging
from drawing_utils import draw_contours
from colors import COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE


class MotionDetector:
    LAPLACIAN = 1.4
    DETECT_DELAY = 1
    

    def __init__(self, video, coordinates, start_frame):
        self.video = 0
        self.coordinates_data = coordinates
        self.start_frame = start_frame
        self.contours = []
        self.bounds = []
        self.mask = []

    def detect_motion(self):
        capture = open_cv.VideoCapture(self.video)
        capture.set(open_cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.start_frame)

        coordinates_data = self.coordinates_data
        logging.debug("coordinates data: %s", coordinates_data)
        
        for p in coordinates_data:
            coordinates = self._coordinates(p)
            logging.debug("coordinates: %s", coordinates)

            rect = open_cv.boundingRect(coordinates)
            logging.debug("rect: %s", rect)

            new_coordinates = coordinates.copy()
            new_coordinates[:, 0] = coordinates[:, 0] - rect[0]
            new_coordinates[:, 1] = coordinates[:, 1] - rect[1]
            logging.debug("new_coordinates: %s", new_coordinates)

            self.contours.append(coordinates)
            self.bounds.append(rect)

            mask = open_cv.drawContours(
                np.zeros((rect[3], rect[2]), dtype=np.uint8),
                [new_coordinates],
                contourIdx=-1,
                color=255,
                thickness=-1,
                lineType=open_cv.LINE_8)

            mask = mask == 255
            self.mask.append(mask)
            logging.debug("mask: %s", self.mask)

        statuses = [False] * len(coordinates_data)
        times = [None] * len(coordinates_data)
        

        while capture.isOpened():
            result, frame = capture.read()
            if frame is None:
                break

            if not result:
                raise CaptureReadError("Error reading video capture on frame %s" % str(frame))

            blurred = open_cv.GaussianBlur(frame.copy(), (5, 5), 3)
            grayed = open_cv.cvtColor(blurred, open_cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            new_frame = frame.copy()
            logging.debug("new_frame: %s", new_frame)

            position_in_seconds = capture.get(open_cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) / 1000.0

            for index, c in enumerate(coordinates_data):
                status = self.__apply(grayed, index, c)

                if times[index] is not None and self.same_status(statuses, index, status):
                    times[index] = None
                    continue

                if times[index] is not None and self.status_changed(statuses, index, status):
                    if position_in_seconds - times[index] >= MotionDetector.DETECT_DELAY:
                        statuses[index] = status
                        times[index] = None
                    continue

                if times[index] is None and self.status_changed(statuses, index, status):
                    times[index] = position_in_seconds

            for index, p in enumerate(coordinates_data):
                coordinates = self._coordinates(p)

                color = COLOR_GREEN if statuses[index] else COLOR_BLUE
                draw_contours(new_frame, coordinates, str(p["id"] + 1), COLOR_WHITE, color)

            open_cv.imshow(str(self.video), new_frame)
            k = open_cv.waitKey(1)
            if k == ord("q"):
                break
                
    
        capture.release()
        open_cv.destroyAllWindows()

    def __apply(self, grayed, index, p):
        coordinates = self._coordinates(p)
        logging.debug("points: %s", coordinates)

        rect = self.bounds[index]
        logging.debug("rect: %s", rect)

        roi_gray = grayed[rect[1]:(rect[1] + rect[3]), rect[0]:(rect[0] + rect[2])]
        laplacian = open_cv.Laplacian(roi_gray, open_cv.CV_64F)
        logging.debug("laplacian: %s", laplacian)

        coordinates[:, 0] = coordinates[:, 0] - rect[0]
        coordinates[:, 1] = coordinates[:, 1] - rect[1]

        status = np.mean(np.abs(laplacian * self.mask[index])) < MotionDetector.LAPLACIAN
        logging.debug("status: %s", status)

        return status
    
    @staticmethod
    def _coordinates(p):
        return np.array(p["coordinates"])

    @staticmethod
    def same_status(coordinates_status, index, status):
        return status == coordinates_status[index]

    @staticmethod
    def status_changed(coordinates_status, index, status):
        return status != coordinates_status[index]


class CaptureReadError(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: Try calling 'out.write(new_frame)' right under 'open_cv.imshow()'.

Comment: im sorry if my question is like a dumb sir @StephenMeschke but im not really understand what sir really means. im sorry :(

Comment: I have clarified my comment in an answer.

Comment: ok sir @StephenMeschke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file for the video to go in. You can think of this file like a book, but a book with no pages. This code is used to create the file:

```
fourcc = open_cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = open_cv.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

Not all codecs work on all systems. I use Ubuntu, and this is the code I use to create a video file:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 30,(w,h))
```

If you try to play this video, nothing will happen. There are no frames in the video, so there is nothing to play (like a book with no pages). After you process each frame, the frame needs to be written to the video (like putting a page in a book):

```
out.write(new_frame)
```

You should do this around `.imshow()`:

```
out.write(new_frame)
open_cv.imshow(str(self.video), new_frame)
k = open_cv.waitKey(1)
if k == ord("q"):
    break
```

Comment: Tq sir.. i finally can save the video based on your answer... i add out.write(new_frame) and everything work exellently